# SnowFlake - Is there a maximum number of fields in a table?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

In SnowFlake, do you know if is there a limit in terms of number of columns in one table ?
Thks

Regards,

François

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67132535/how-to-test-snowflake-abilities-to-handle-tables-with-thousands-of-columns

Answer (score 3):

The number of columns that can be created in a Snowflake table is limited by the  the size of a partition . In Snowflake this is around 16MB ,  in compressed format.
So depending on the type of datatype that you define the number would vary.

However,  there is a soft limit of about 2000 columns. It also depends on the type of account you hold, whether it is a self-signed account etc.

Hope this helps

Comment: For the record: I created a table with 2001 columns without a problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67132535/how-to-test-snowflake-abilities-to-handle-tables-with-thousands-of-columns

Answer (score 0):

The published limit that you must be most concerned with is the 1 MB query length limit. https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/query-size-limits.html

Hard to do anything gigantic with that kind of scripting limit.