# How to create a table with hundreds of columns in Snowflake?

Tags: python, pandas, migration, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am using Python on Snowflake where I need to move a pandas dataframe with hundreds of columns to Snowflake.  I am at loss to figure out a way to do so without typing in each column name and its data type in "`Create Table` ..." inside the snowflake connector cursor.

Does anyone know any advise?  Any guidance will be helpful.

Thank you

Comment: Could you try iterating through $1,$2 ect The $# is another way to reference the column.

Answer (score 0):

Pandas `.toSql()` should work. If you tried it and it didn't get you the results you wanted - please include those details in your question.

The following can create the table with the correct schema:

```py
df.head(0).to_sql(
  'MY_TABLE', con=connection, if_exists="replace", index=False)
```

Otherwise, see below.

- https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.21/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html
- https://cloudyard.in/2022/01/snowflake-create-empty-table-using-df-head0-to_sql/

---

You don't need to "type" every column and its data type, you can use Python to generate a `create table` statement to match your dataframe.

I did something similar with JS:

```sql
CREATE or replace PROCEDURE create_wide_table()
  RETURNS VARCHAR
  LANGUAGE javascript
  AS
  $$
ss = 'create or replace table wide2000 (id int';
for (const x of Array(2000).keys()) {
  ss += ', a' +x + ' int default uniform(1, 10000, random())';
}
ss += ');'
//return ss;
  var rs = snowflake.execute( { sqlText:  ss       } );
  return 'Done.';
  $$;
```

That will generate and execute a SQL query that looks like:

```sql
create or replace table wide2000 
  (id int
   , a0 int default uniform(1, 10000, random())
   , a1 int default uniform(1, 10000, random())
   , ...
);
```

(from https://stackoverflow.com/a/67132536/132438)

In your case, use Python to iterate over the dataframe column names and types, and generate the `create table`.